# PostgreSQL : Transaction and foreign key problem

Tags: postgresql, transactions, foreign-keys

I'm inserting a value in table A, that has a serial type as primary key. I wanna use the returned value of the query as a foreign key of table B... but I get this message:

*ERROR: insert or update on table "tb_midia_pessoa" violates foreign key constraint "tb_midia_pessoa_id_pessoa_fkey" DETAIL: Key (id_pessoa)=(30) is not present in table "tb_pessoa". )*

How can I make this possible without:

- starting a new Transaction
- droping my foreign keys constraints =O
  ?

Regards!
Pedro

Comment: Can you be more clear how "Table A" and "Table B" correspond to "tb_midia_pessoa" and "tb_pessoa"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can make a deferrable FK, just use DEFERRABLE and maybe INITIALLY DEFERRED, that's up to you.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 8):

The statement below allows non-deferrable constraints to be deferred until transaction committed. If you don't want to change FK definitions.

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

Comment: Actually, current documentation states not deferrable constraints are not affected at all by this statement: Upon creation, a constraint is given one of three characteristics: DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, or NOT DEFERRABLE. The third class is always IMMEDIATE and is not affected by the SET CONSTRAINTS command. The first two classes start every transaction in the indicated mode, but their behavior can be changed within a transaction by SET CONSTRAINTS.

Comment: When should you run that? After you start a transaction?